# Windows Store app background audio from sharetarget

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

Is it possible to play background audio from ShareTarget flyout?

As soon as flyout is closed, audio stops playing. Is there any way to workaround that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in MainPage MediaElement that can play background audio.

Add a static class to the project that will raise an event for playing background audio.

ShareTarget page should raise the event, and MainPage should subscribe to that event and in the event handler have command that will play audio.